# Lighttpd 403 Errors on HTML and PHP pages

Tags: permissions, lighttpd, centos5, chmod, chown

I installed lighttpd on CentOS 5.5 64-bit.  Everything seems fine and running except I cannot get past 403 errors on both HTML and PHP pages.  I have used CHMOD and CHOWN, changed ownership in the config file, done everything possible and have been stuck for 2 days.  Appreciate any help, and here's hoping to a stupid error on my part.

Here is the log file with debug options on:

```
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (request.c.304) fd: 7 request-len: 408 
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.1.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0


2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.241) run condition 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.301) Request-URI  :  /index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  http 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.303) URI-authority:  10.0.1.8 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.304) URI-path     :  /index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.305) URI-query    :   
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.349) -- sanatising URI 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.350) URI-path     :  /index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.470) -- before doc_root 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.471) Doc-Root     : /srv/www/lighttpd 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.472) Rel-Path     : /index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.473) Path         :  
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.521) -- after doc_root 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.522) Doc-Root     : /srv/www/lighttpd 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.523) Rel-Path     : /index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.524) Path         : /srv/www/lighttpd/index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.541) -- logical -> physical 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.542) Doc-Root     : /srv/www/lighttpd 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.543) Rel-Path     : /index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.544) Path         : /srv/www/lighttpd/index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.561) -- handling physical path 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.562) Path         : /srv/www/lighttpd/index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.608) -- access denied 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.609) Path         : /srv/www/lighttpd/index.html 
2011-02-21 11:23:13: (response.c.128) Response-Header: 
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 345
Date: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 16:23:13 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
```

Here is the directory listing.  I used CHOWN to set to lighttpd:lighttpd

```
[root@localhost lighttpd]# ls -al
total 40
drwxrwxrwx 2 lighttpd lighttpd 4096 Feb 21 10:48 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 lighttpd lighttpd 4096 Feb 21 10:57 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lighttpd lighttpd   10 Feb 20 08:32 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lighttpd lighttpd   20 Feb 21 10:48 index.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lighttpd lighttpd   20 Feb 21 10:39 info.php
[root@localhost lighttpd]#
```

Requested Commands:

```
[root@localhost lighttpd]# ls -ld / /srv /srv/www
drwxr-xr-x 22 root     root     4096 Feb 21 04:39 /
drwxrwxrwx  3 lighttpd lighttpd 4096 Feb 20 07:38 /srv
drwxrwxrwx  3 lighttpd lighttpd 4096 Feb 21 10:57 /srv/www

[root@localhost lighttpd]# ps auxZ | grep lighttpd
root:system_r:httpd_t           lighttpd  3842  0.0  0.2  48368   896 ?        S    12:24   0:00 /usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
root:system_r:unconfined_t:SystemLow-SystemHigh root 3845 0.0  0.2 61152 764 pts/0 R+ 12:24   0:00 grep lighttpd
```

Comment: Give us `ls -ld / /srv /srv/www`.  If you have SELinux enabled, check `/var/log/audit.log` or `/var/log/messages` and repeat ls commands with `-Z`, also `ps auxZ | grep lighttpd`.

Comment: `[root@localhost lighttpd]# ls -ld / /srv /srv/www
drwxr-xr-x 22 root     root     4096 Feb 21 04:39 /
drwxrwxrwx  3 lighttpd lighttpd 4096 Feb 20 07:38 /srv
drwxrwxrwx  3 lighttpd lighttpd 4096 Feb 21 10:57 /srv/www`

Comment: @DerfK, added ls -ld up in original.  I have recently tried to run as nobody:nobody which I have another server configured like that, no luck here.  Don't have SELinux enabled.

Comment: you have enough of SELinux enabled to have a LABEL column with actual SELinux labels in your `ps auxZ` ;)